# Averaging across multiple fields with IntSummaryStatistics

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use Java 8 streams to create a single CarData object, which consists of an average of all the CarData fields in the list coming from `getCars`;

```
   CarData = new CarData();
   CarData.getBodyWeight returns Integer
   CarData.getShellWeight returns Integer
```

---

```
     List<CarData> carData = carResults.getCars();
    
    IntSummaryStatistics averageBodyWeight = carData.stream()
            .mapToInt((x) -> x.getBodyWeight())
            .summaryStatistics();
    
    averageBodyWeight.getAverage(); 


            IntSummaryStatistics averageShellWeight = carData.stream()
            .mapToInt((x) -> x.getShellWeight())
            .summaryStatistics();
    
    getShellWeight.getAverage();
```

I don't want to have to put each of these back together in my final returned result.

Visually, this is my list

```
getCars() : [
 {CarData: { getBodyWeight=10, getShellWeight=3 } }
 {CarData: { getBodyWeight=6, getShellWeight=5 } }
 {CarData: { getBodyWeight=8, getShellWeight=19 } }
]
```

and the output I'm trying to achieve is a single object that has the average of each of the fields I specify. not sure If I need to use `Collectors.averagingInt` or some combo of IntSummaryStatistics to achieve this. Easy to do across one field for either of these techniques, just not sure what I'm missing when using multiple integer fields.

```
 {CarData: { getBodyWeight=8, getShellWeight=9 } }
```

Comment: I don't think streams offer this functionality. You could make a different collector thought that creates the average CarData object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write your own `Collector`, something like this:

```java
class CarDataAverage {
    public static Collector<CarData, CarDataAverage, Optional<CarData>> get() {
        return Collector.of(CarDataAverage::new, CarDataAverage::add,
                            CarDataAverage::combine,CarDataAverage::finish);
    }
    private long sumBodyWeight;
    private long sumShellWeight;
    private int count;
    private void add(CarData carData) {
        this.sumBodyWeight += carData.getBodyWeight();
        this.sumShellWeight += carData.getShellWeight();
        this.count++;
    }
    private CarDataAverage combine(CarDataAverage that) {
        this.sumBodyWeight += that.sumBodyWeight;
        this.sumShellWeight += that.sumShellWeight;
        this.count += that.count;
        return this;
    }
    private Optional<CarData> finish() {
        if (this.count == 0)
            return Optional.empty();
        // adjust as needed if averages should be rounded
        return Optional.of(new CarData((int) (this.sumBodyWeight / this.count),
                                       (int) (this.sumShellWeight / this.count)));
    }
}
```

You then use it like this:

```java
List<CarData> list = ...

Optional<CarData> averageCarData = list.stream().collect(CarDataAverage.get());
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting with JDK 12, you can use the following solution:

```
CarData average = carData.stream().collect(Collectors.teeing(
    Collectors.averagingInt(CarData::getBodyWeight),
    Collectors.averagingInt(CarData::getShellWeight),
    (avgBody, avgShell) -> new CarData(avgBody.intValue(), avgShell.intValue())));
```

For older Java versions, you can do either, add the `teeing` implementation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030899/2711488) to your code base and use it exactly as above or create a custom collector tailored to your task, as shown in [Andreas’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63810043/2711488).

Or consider that streaming twice over a `List` in memory is not necessarily worse than doing two operations in one stream, both, readability- and performance-wise.

Note that calling `intValue()` on `Double` objects has the same behavior as the `(int)` casts in Andreas’ answer. So in either case, you have to adjust the code if other rounding behavior is intended.

Or you consider using a different result object, capable of holding two floating point values for the averages.

Comment: Oh man that's beautiful. Unfortunately JDK 8 here, but good to know.