# Aggregate values and convert into single type within the same Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I have a class with a collection of `Seed` elements. One of the method's return type of `Seed` is `Optional<Pair<Boolean, String>>`.

I'm trying to loop over all `seeds`, find if any `boolean` value is `true` and at the same time, create a set with all the `String` values. For instance, my input is in the form `Optional<Pair<Boolean, String>>`, the output should be `Optional<Signal>` where `Signal` is like:

```java
class Signal {
   public boolean exposure;

   public Set<String> alarms;

   // constructor and getters (can add anything to this class, it's just a bag)
}
```

This is what I currently have that works:

```java
// Seed::hadExposure yields Optional<Pair<Boolean, String>> where Pair have key/value or left/right
public Optional<Signal> withExposure() {
  if (seeds.stream().map(Seed::hadExposure).flatMap(Optional::stream).findAny().isEmpty()) {
    return Optional.empty();
  }
  final var exposure = seeds.stream()
      .map(Seed::hadExposure)
      .flatMap(Optional::stream)
      .anyMatch(Pair::getLeft);
  final var alarms = seeds.stream()
      .map(Seed::hadExposure)
      .flatMap(Optional::stream)
      .map(Pair::getRight)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  return Optional.of(new Signal(exposure, alarms));
}
```

Now I have time to make it better because `Seed::hadExposure` could become and expensive call, so I was trying to see if I could make all of this with only one pass. I've tried (some suggestions from previous questions) with `reduce`, using collectors (`Collectors.collectingAndThen`, `Collectors.partitioningBy`, etc.), but nothing so far.

Comment: what is the first `if` intended for?

Comment: You should stop overusing `Optional`, especially in this inconsistent way, i.e. returning an `Optional` that contains a `Pair` that may contain `null`. But if you want to keep this logic, you can do it with a single `public Optional<Signal> withExposure() { return seeds.stream() .map(Seed::hadExposure) .flatMap(Optional::stream) .collect(teeing( mapping(Pair::getLeft, reducing(Boolean::logicalOr)), mapping(Pair::getRight, filtering(Objects::nonNull, toSet())), (o,set) -> o.map(b -> new Signal(b,set)))); }` But `teeing` needs JDK 12 or [a backport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030899/2711488).

Comment: I don't understand why do you say that. The `Optional` value wraps a `Pair`, what's inside that `Pair` could be what's inside any other object. I don't control the values coming from `Pair` but I do control what happens after it.

Comment: The question is, *what does it mean* when the optional is empty, *what does it mean* when the string is null. It couldn’t be less obvious…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this in a single `stream()` expression using `map` to convert the non-empty exposure to a `Signal` and then a `reduce` to combine the signals:

```java
Signal signal = exposures.stream()
    .map(exposure ->
        new Signal(
            exposure.getLeft(),
            exposure.getRight() == null
                ? Collections.emptySet()
                : Collections.singleton(exposure.getRight())))
    .reduce(
        new Signal(false, new HashSet<>()),
        (leftSig, rightSig) -> {
            HashSet<String> alarms = new HashSet<>();
            alarms.addAll(leftSig.alarms);
            alarms.addAll(rightSig.alarms);
            return new Signal(
                leftSig.exposure || rightSig.exposure, alarms);
        });
```

However, if you have a lot of alarms it would be expensive because it creates a new `Set` and adds the new alarms to the accumulated alarms for each exposure in the input.

In a language that was designed from the ground-up to support functional programming, like Scala or Haskell, you'd have a `Set` data type that would let you [efficiently create a new set that's identical to an existing set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) but with an added element, so there'd be no efficiency worries:

```scala
filteredSeeds.foldLeft((false, Set[String]())) { (result, exposure) => 
  (result._1 || exposure.getLeft, result._2 + exposure.getRight)
}
```

But Java doesn't come with anything like that out of the box.

You could create just a single `Set` for the result and mutate it in your stream's `reduce` expression, but some would regard that as poor style because you'd be mixing a functional paradigm (map/reduce over a stream) with a procedural one (mutating a set).

Personally, in Java, I'd just ditch the functional approach and use a `for` loop in this case.  It'll be less code, more efficient, and IMO clearer.

If you have enough space to store an intermediate result, you could do something like:

```
List<Pair<Boolean, String>> exposures = 
    seeds.stream()
        .map(Seed::hadExposure)
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you'd only be calling the expensive `Seed::hadExposure` method once per item in the input list.

Comment: A for loop solution equivalent to the code in question might look like  following `var empty = true; var exposure = false; var alarms = new ArrayList<>(); for (Seed seed : seeds) { Optional<Pair<Boolean, String>> optionalPair = seed.hadExposure();
            if (optionalPair.isPresent() && empty) { empty = false;
                if (optionalPair.get().getLeft()) {  exposure = true; }
                String right = optionalPair.get().getRight();
                if (right != null) {  alarms.add(right);  } } } return empty ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(new Signal(exposure, alarms));`