# Mapping a stream to an instance of another object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a class `CarPart` defined as:

```
class CarPart {
  String name;
  BigDecimal price;
  Supplier supplier;
}
```

A class `Report`:

```
class Report {
   List<Part> parts;
   BigDecimal total;
}
```

and a class `Part`:

```
class Part {
  String name;
  String supplierName;
}
```

Given a `Stream<CarPart> carParts`, I need to create a `Report` object.

My idea to handle this, is to create a `Map<List<Part>, BigDecimal>` where the `List<Part>` is a list of the transformed `CarPart` objects, and the `BigDecimal` is the sum of the prices of all car parts in the given stream. Afterwards, I could access the `Map<>` which would contain a single entry, and I could create a new `Report`.

I started doing that, but I am not sure how to collect it. After the `.map` I am doing below, I have in practice a `Map<Part, BigDecimal>` but I need to summarize all the `Part` objects in a list, and add all the `BigDecimal` to create the total value for the `Report`.

```
   carParts.stream()
           .map(x -> {
               return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new Part(x.getName(), x.supplier.getName()), x.getPrice());
           })
           .collect(.....)
```

Am I handling it completely wrong? I am trying to iterate the stream only once.

P.S: Assume that all getters and setters are available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Java 12+ solution

If you're on Java 12+:

```java
carParts.collect(teeing(
    mapping(p -> new Part(p.name, p.supplier.name), toList()),
    mapping(p -> p.price, reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)),
    Report::new
));
```

Assuming this static import:

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

#### Solution using third party collectors

If a third party library is an option, which offers tuples and tuple collectors (e.g. [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL)), you can do this even before Java 12

```java
carParts.collect(Tuple.collectors(
    mapping(p -> new Part(p.name, p.supplier.name), toList()),
    mapping(p -> p.price, reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))
)).map(Report::new);
```

You can roll your own `Tuple.collectors()` if you want, of course, replacing `Tuple2` by `Map.Entry`:

```java
static <T, A1, A2, D1, D2> Collector<T, Tuple2<A1, A2>, Tuple2<D1, D2>> collectors(
    Collector<? super T, A1, D1> collector1
  , Collector<? super T, A2, D2> collector2
) {
    return Collector.<T, Tuple2<A1, A2>, Tuple2<D1, D2>>of(
        () -> tuple(
            collector1.supplier().get()
          , collector2.supplier().get()
        ),
        (a, t) -> {
            collector1.accumulator().accept(a.v1, t);
            collector2.accumulator().accept(a.v2, t);
        },
        (a1, a2) -> tuple(
            collector1.combiner().apply(a1.v1, a2.v1)
          , collector2.combiner().apply(a1.v2, a2.v2)
        ),
        a -> tuple(
            collector1.finisher().apply(a.v1)
          , collector2.finisher().apply(a.v2)
        )
    );
}
```

Disclaimer: I made jOOλ

#### Solution using Java 8 only and continuing with your attempts

You asked me in the comments to finish what you've started. I don't think that's the right way. The right way is to implement a collector (or use the suggested third party collector, I don't see why that wouldn't be an option) that does the same thing as the JDK 12 collector `Collectors.teeing()`.

But here you go, this is one way how you could have completed what you've started:

```java
carParts

    // Stream<SimpleEntry<Part, BigDecimal>>
    .map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
        new Part(x.name, x.supplier.name), x.price))

    // Map<Integer, Report>
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(

        // A dummy map key. I don't really need it, I just want access to
        // the Collectors.toMap()'s mergeFunction
        e -> 1, 

        // A single entry report. This just shows that the intermediate
        // step of creating a Map.Entry wasn't really useful anyway
        e -> new Report(
            Collections.singletonList(e.getKey()), 
            e.getValue()), 

        // Merging two intermediate reports
        (r1, r2) -> {
            List<Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
            parts.addAll(r1.parts);
            parts.addAll(r2.parts);
            return new Report(parts, r1.total.add(r2.total));
        }

    // We never needed the map.
    )).get(1);
```

There are many other ways to do something similar. You could also use the `Stream.collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer)` overload to implement an ad-hoc collector, or use `Collector.of()` to create one.

But really. Use some variant of `Collectors.teeing()`. Or even an imperative loop, rather than the above.

Comment: A simpler Java-8 compatible `teeing` implementation can be found in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030899/1746118)

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder ! Unfortunately, I am running on Java 8..  How could I do this without a 3rd party library?

Comment: @maria82: You copy paste the `collectors()` method and adapt it to your needs, or follow the link by @Naman

Comment: @maria82: No, it's not totally wrong, it just feels more laborious. Having such a teeing utility in your codebase will be useful time and again, irrespective of whether you're using the Java 12 one, a third party one, or your own.

Comment: @LukasEder would you mind providing an example based on my laborious approach? I am just curious to see how I could combine Collectors to achieve what I need. I have tried many many things. I would appreciate an example if you have the time.

Comment: @maria82: Well, I really don't recommend continuing with what you started, but I mean, many roads lead to Rome :)

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you very very much Lukas! I really appreciate it

Comment: Your `.collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> 1, …)).get(1)` is a `reduce` in disguise. Combine the `.map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(new Part(x.name, x.supplier.name), x.price))` and the `e -> new Report(Collections.singletonList(e.getKey()), e.getValue())` function to a single `.map(x -> new Report(Collections.singletonList(new Part(x.name, x.supplier.name)), x.price))`. Then, use the merge function as reduction function, e.g. `.reduce( /* the merge function without any changes */).orElseGet(() -> new Report(Collections.emptyList(), BigDecimal.ZERO))`.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger: I would not have added such a silly `collect()` solution to my answer if it hadn't been an explicit request to complete what had already been started. I could have used `Collectors.reducing()` maybe, but is it even worth the trouble? I added a disclaimer, and the best solution here is to use `teeing()`

Answer (score 3):

#### With a mutable `Report` class

When the `Report` class is mutable and you have the necessary access to modify it, you can use

```java
Report report = carParts.stream()
   .collect(
        () -> new Report(new ArrayList<>(), BigDecimal.ZERO),
        (r, cp) -> {
            r.parts.add(new Part(cp.getName(), cp.supplier.getName()));
            r.total = r.total.add(cp.getPrice());
        },
        (r1, r2) -> { r1.parts.addAll(r2.parts); r1.total = r1.total.add(r2.total); });
```

#### With an immutable `Report` class

When you can’t modify `Report` instances, you have to use a temporary mutable object for the processing and create a final result object afterwards. Otherwise, the operation is similar:

```java
Report report = carParts.stream()
   .collect(Collector.of(
        () -> new Object() {
            List<Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
            BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        },
        (r, cp) -> {
            r.parts.add(new Part(cp.getName(), cp.supplier.getName()));
            r.total = r.total.add(cp.getPrice());
        },
        (r1, r2) -> {
            r1.parts.addAll(r2.parts);
            r1.total = r1.total.add(r2.total);
            return r1;
        },
        tmp -> new Report(tmp.parts, tmp.total)));
```

Well, in principle, you don’t need mutable objects but could implement the operation as a pure Reduction, however a [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) aka `collect` operation is more efficient for this specific purpose (i.e. when collecting values into a `List`).